# Jquery Tagit not working with master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages, tag-it

Here I am getting problem with master page. Here When I am using `Jquery Tagit` with a simple `.aspx` page then `Jquery Tagit`is woking fine but when I use of Jquery tagit with `.master` page
then I am getting error.

**Error as Below**

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tagit'
```

Above Error I am getting as below line.

```
$('#<%=Tbmytags.ClientID%>').tagit();
```

**Mater page source code**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/admin.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Upload_content.aspx.vb" Inherits="Upload_content" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
        <link href="css/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/tagit.ui-zendesk.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="js/tag-it.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/ecmascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#<%=Tbmytags.ClientID%>').tagit();
            });
        </script>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Tag Name</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Tbmytags" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                
        </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

If somebody have any idea about this error then please help me